# jquery webUI popover can not be focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popover, webui

I have a problem with webUI popover. I have 2 links that open popovers onclick and want to be able to copy the contents of both popovers without reloading the page. When I open one popover and try to do that everything goes as planed, but when I try to focus another popover after I did that to the first one it just disappears. Could someone help me with this problem?

html example:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <a class="popover_hot" title="HOT" data-content="hot">
        hot
    </a>

    <a class="popover_cold" title="COLD" data-content="cold">
        cold
    </a>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.popover_hot').webuiPopover({
  animation: 'pop',
  placement: 'bottom-right',
  trigger: 'click'
});
$('.popover_cold').webuiPopover({
  animation: 'pop',
  placement: 'bottom-right',
  trigger: 'click'
});
```

JsFiddle [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/8otoqg51/)

Comment: So you want both popups to remain open if clicked simultaneously?

Comment: No, my main struggle is to be able to focus open popover. Try open "cold" popover and copy content and after that try open "hot" popover and copy content. The "hot" popover will disappear onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dismissible:false` and `multi:true` options